# SSIS - Integration Services Catalog Deployment & Logging

Tags: sql-server, logging, deployment, ssis, sql-server-2012

We are using SSIS 2012. I am pretty new to it. My target is to custom logging

1. Execution start/end times of tasks/package
2. record counts (both extraction & loading) in the DFT
3. errors
4. events

Please note that in the package there could be **several DFTs** which may contain multiple source(s) and destination(s).

Very recently while I was sifting info on the internet, I came across the concept of SSIS package Catalog Deployment functionality which supposedly provides several log tables (e.g.[executions], [execution_parameter_values], [executable_statistics], [execution_data_statistics] etc) in SSISDB to capture metadata pertaining to package execution, performance, parameters, configurations etc extensively.

I wish to be cognizant if my understanding is correct and if this feature can be leveraged to capture log data for auditing, performance analysis etc. Also, I am keen to know if this feature will log automatically to the SSISDB (when deployed thru **CATALOG**) OR if, it is required that the package(s) would somehow need to be configured/setup to avail this functionality during execution.can we enable such ATALOG**s these logging will work automatically versus any settings/configuration that needs to be enabled in SSIS first facilitate such logging metadata to SSISDB catalog tables.

Having found this topic and consequently hopeful of its potential, I am inclined on leveraging the aforementioned functionality with the hope that leveraging sucha functionality will save a huge amount of effort/time versus implementing the same by coding.

NB: Additionally I would like to understand its limitations (if any) of this approach that could possibly manifest itself as a showstopper after being deployed in production.

Please share your thoughts. and point to me to any informative and relevant resources on the net.

MSDN help resource [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh479588.aspx).

Thanks